# Template enable_if for arithmetic AND complex numbers

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I have the following template-statement that works for int's, floats, doubles:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type > struct Matrix
{
    //...
};
```

I want to extend it to cover complex numbers as well. How do I add/change the above for that. Or am I going for overkill and should just use vanilla template?

---

[edit - based on HolyBlackCat's answer]
This works:

```
template<typename T> concept bool IsNmberOrComplex() { return (std::is_convertible<T, double>::value || std::is_convertible<T, std::complex<decltype(T())>>::value); }

template<IsNmberOrComplex T> struct Matrix
```

As per HolyBlackCat this is not proper c++20. If you can supply such an answer, pls do so.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to include solutions. Feel free to post an answer if you have a solution to the question.

Comment: @cigien: The edit form part of the question as a proposed solution. If You look at HolyBlackCat's last comment, there _is_ a problem with it. Please restore the edit you removed so that someone else can have an opportunity to give a correct c++20 solution.

Comment: I don't follow. Your edit says "this works". If it does work, then it's a solution, and shouldn't be in the question. If it doesn't work, you should edit the question to say that, and explain exactly why it doesn't work.

Comment: @cigien: what are you having difficulty with? It is something that works. It is not ideal, Therfor it is not an answer. Someone may have an ideal answer. That person can see my code. Then that person can answer.

Comment: Basically, the issue with your edit is that it makes this question a discussion thread, which is not appropriate for a Q&A format. You're not supposed to edit a question to ask follow up questions to provided answers. In this particular case, the correct approach would be to post a new question, possibly linking to this one, asking why your seemingly correct solution is wrong. (In this case, that's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684179, among others, but in general, you should ask a separate question). I'm rolling back the edit again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <template <typename...> typename T, typename U>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of_v = false;

template <template <typename...> typename T, typename ...P>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of_v<T, T<P...>> = true;
```

Then `is_specialization_of_v<std::complex, T>` will tell you if `T` is `std::complex<...>` or not.

---

Note that this kind of SFINAE on a class template is not the best idea, since it can be disabled trivially by passing a custom template argument. Consider using `requires` from C++20 (and if you can use C++20, `is_specialization_of_v` can be turned into a `concept`).

Comment: Your idea for using `concept` works! - thx. (and some people call concepts "syntactic sugar" - they are wrong)

Comment: @slashmais They're right, I think. There's nothing you can do with concepts that you can't do without them.

Comment: ...uhmmm - compare the concept I use now to the templates in your answer: which is the easier to understand? Sugar it may be, but the clarity it gives makes-up for that.

Comment: @slashmais Yeah, I agree that they're useful. But probably count as sugar.

Comment: The syntax you used in the edit is not valid C++20. It might be an experimental syntax in an older compiler version. Consider updating the compiler and switching to the proper syntax.